# Did Sliders predict the future of a 'cashless society' in this episode?

Tags: sliders

The sliders arrive (in '[Seasons Greedings](https://sliders.fandom.com/wiki/Season%27s_Greedings)') on a world where there are malls and no cash.

Did they predict the future of a 'cashless society' in this episode?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Digital cash was a staple of cyberpunk in the '80s, so I'm gonna say "no."  For future reference, it would help make your question better if you showed the research you did before asking it.

Answer (score 3):

*Seasons Greedings* isn't a good example of a cashless society. It's clear from the reaction of the server that cash is instantly recognised (and hence is presumably accepted elsewhere outside of the mall), just not *inside the mall where they only accept plaza-cards*. You may also wish to note that the cards aren't loaded with 'mall credits', but rather with dollars.

> **Mallory:** *Keep the change*
>
> **Server:** *We don't take cash. Only your plaza-club card. Your debit card? Sorry, I'm really sorry.*

Since we see people coming into the mall from outside, it seems reasonable that there's some way of translating cash money (including paper cash) into debit card money, presumably via a bank or through their employer.

This isn't unlike our world where [some venues no longer accept cash](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/pub-cash-payment-uk-first-boot-freston-ipswich-suffolk-a8543181.html). That doesn't mean that we live in a cashless world.